# Insertion sort array java

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

So I have to write code for an insertion sort that will sort an array of random ints, the array is already set up and working okay and everything but my sort is not, heres what i have:

```
 for(int i =1; i< numberSort.length-1;i++){
        int temp = numberSort[i];
        int j = i-1;
        while((j >= 0) && (numberSort[j]>temp)){
            numberSort[j+1] = numberSort[j];
            j = j-1;
        }
        numberSort[j+1] = temp;          
    }
}
```

It seems to me that that should work, however it does not, it moves the numbers around from their original position but does not order them in ascending order. Thanks for any help you may be able to offer.

Comment: If it is not about the algorithmic part try: Arrays.sort(numberSort);

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numberSort = {22,7,2, 5, 7, 1, 2, 9,33,55,12,1,0};
        for (int i = 1; i < numberSort.length; i++) {
            int temp = numberSort[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            while ((j >= 0) && (numberSort[j] > temp)) {
                numberSort[j + 1] = numberSort[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            numberSort[j + 1] = temp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numberSort.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(numberSort[i]);
        }
    }
```

Gives output:

```
0
1
1
2
2
5
7
7
9
12
22
33
55
```

Comment: Hmm.. Im not sure what to do.. my array is already created and filled by the time it gets to this sort method, So im not entirely sure why it isn't working like yours is

Comment: Post your whole code.